# ZipArchive::close(): Failure to create temporary file: No error

Tags: phpexcel, php-ziparchive

I'm using `Yii2 - phpExcel` to export data. But only in my localhost (Windows - XAMPP - PHP7), there is an error: **

> **ZipArchive::close(): Failure to create temporary file: No error**

**
[image]

This **screenshoot** is my test code and it returned the same error. My **Xampp** Setting is default. I can't find anythings helpful in internet. Please Help me. Thank you so much.

Comment: Dont use `/tmp` directly, as your setup might not allow it, instead use `tempnam("/tmp", "test.zip")` which will handle it for you and return a filename you can work with.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone thank you! it return other error: tempnam(): file created in the system's temporary directory.